# Using C I would like to format my output such that the output in the terminal stops once it hits the edge of the window

Tags: c, printf, output, word-wrap

If you type `ps aux` into your terminal and make the window really small, the output of the command will not wrap and the format is still very clear.

When I use printf and output my 5 or 6 strings, sometimes the length of my output exceeds that of the terminal window and the strings wrap to the next line which totally screws up the format. How can I write my program such that the output continues to the edge of the window but no further?

I've tried searching for an answer to this question but I'm having trouble narrowing it down and thus my search results never have anything to do with it so it seems.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to find the size of your terminal, and you need to adapt your output to that size.  Search for TIOCGWINSZ. It’s distinctive.

Answer (score 2):

There are functions that can let you know information about the terminal window, and some others that will allow you to manipulate it.  Look up the "ncurses" or the "termcap" library.

A simple approach for solving your problem will be to get the terminal window size (specially the width), and then format your output accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers to fix your problem.

1. Turn off line wrapping in your terminal emulator(if it supports it).
2. Look into the Curses library. Applications like top or vim use the Curses library for screen formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can find, or at least guess, the width of the terminal using methods that other answers describe. That's only part of the problem however -- the tricky bit is formatting the output to fit the console. I don't believe there's any alternative to reading the text word by word, and moving the output to the next line when a word would overflow the width. You'll need to implement a method to detect where the white-space is, allowing for the fact that there could be multiple white spaces in a row. You'll need to decide how to handle line-breaking white-space, like CR/LF, if you have any. You'll need to decide whether you can break a word on punctuation (e.g, a hyphen). My approach is to use a simple finite-state machine, where the states are "At start of line", "in a word", "in whitespace", etc., and the characters (or, rather character classes) encountered are the events that change the state.

A particular complication when working in C is that there is little-to-no built-in support for multi-byte characters. That's fine for text which you are certain will only ever be in English, and use only the ASCII punctuation symbols, but with any kind of internationalization you need to be more careful. I've found that it's easiest to convert the text into some wide format, perhaps UTF-32, and then work with arrays of 32-bit integers to represent the characters. If your text is UTF-8, there are various tricks you can use to avoid having to do this conversion, but they are a bit ugly.

I have some code I could share, but I don't claim it is production quality, or even comprehensible. This simple-seeming problem is actually far more complicated than first impressions suggest. It's easy to do badly, but difficult to do well.